# Generic Constraints in C# Extension Methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to provide a extension method but have some sort of prevention in what can call it.

This is what I have:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
            p.IsValid();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static void IsValid<T>(this T parent) where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("test");
    }
}
```

However, this doesnt stop someone doing `"this is a dumb idea".IsValid();`

I could mark the Person object with an interface, attribute or base class but I don't want to.  Is there any way to enforce the constraints?

**UPDATE:** What I'm try to explain is to enforce constraints for example by namespace because having a string call IsValid is dumb and I only want certain set of model classes

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at AOP? Here's a decent example (http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2009/11/15/validating-business-objects-with-aop-1-the-domain.aspx).  I'm a big fan of PostSharp for furthering your AOP aspirations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces in C# (and .Net overall) is pure syntactic sugar to make class names look shorter. As result of it what you want is "restrict generic by sub-string of full name of the class" which is not supported in C#.

As already suggested you may want to provide the method only for classes where it makes sense instead of doing other way around.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to constrain it to just work on `Person` instances (and types derived from `Person`), you can do:

```
public static void IsValid<T>(this T parent) where T : Person
```

However, there is no reason to do this, as you can easily also write:

```
public static void IsValid(this Person parent)
```

Comment: ... and honestly since he has control over the class, it would be better to just make this an instance method of Person, unless classes other than Person and its descendants must be validated this way.

Comment: @KeithS exactly, its not just Person and derived types. This is for all model classes

Comment: @Jon If this is for all model classes, you'll need some type of base class, like Entity, etc.

Comment: ... Or a defining interface, like IValidatableModelClass, to be used at the GTC. Again, the interface can just as easily require definition of an IsValid() method on all implementations, which could be satisfied by also deriving from a base class as Reed said.

Answer (score 5):

The constraints *are* being enforced.
`string` is a class.

Comment: I know but I want to enforce based on namespace for example

Comment: @Jon there is no way to do that in C#